# Is it a good practice to change arguments in Java

Tags: java, pass-by-value

Suppose I am writing a method `foo(int i)` in Java.
Since `i` is passed by value it is safe to change it in `foo`. For example

```
void foo(int i) {
   i = i + 1; // change i
   ...
}
```

Is it considered good or bad practice to change arguments of methods in Java?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It's considered bad practice in general, though some people overlook it as you can see in the other answers.

For parameters like primitives that are directly passed in by value, there is no advantage in overriding the original variable. In this case you should make a copy as suggested by @João.

For parameters whose *reference* is passed in by value (objects), if you modify the handle to point to a different object, that is downright confusing. It's all the more important because modifying the contents of an object passed as a parameter will modify the original object too.

If you replace the object referred to by the handle, and then modify *its* contents, the object referred to by the original reference in the caller will not be replaced, but someone reading the code might expect it to be.

Whereas if you don't replace the object, and modify the contents, the method *calling* your method might not expect this change. This category generally comes under security-related bad practices.

Comment: Everything is passed by value in Java. Objects are not "passed"; objects are not values.

Comment: Would you feel better if I used the terms call-by-value and call-by-reference instead? Also, what does "objects are not values" mean?

Comment: No. It is always pass-by-value (or "call-by-value"). The only types in Java are primitive types and reference types. Hence the only values are primitives and references, both of which are passed by value. Unlike C++, you cannot have a variable whose value "is" an object; you can only have a variable whose value is a reference that points to an object. Everything you do with objects must be done through a reference -- `new SomeClass()` evaluates to a reference; field and method access use references. That's what "objects are not values" means. You cannot "pass" an object.

Comment: Yes, I read all the arguments on the topic though I still think your choice of phrase is more confusing than helpful. I reworded the answer so let me know if it looks OK now.

Answer (score 8):

It's merely a personal opinion, but I think it can be confusing for other people that may want to use the *original* parameter value later in that code, and may not notice that it has already been changed.

Plus, it's cheap to simply create another variable and assign it the modified value (i.e., `int j = i + 1`).

Comment: My personal opinion differs from yours. Not understanding a method you are making changes to is bad.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe True. But shenanigans makes understanding the method harder than it has to be, and making a distinction between passed-in and (for whatever reason) changed value *can* aid understanding.

Comment: Every opinion in the world is always a personal opinion or a corporate opinion :) The question obviously meant to ask what the general consensus is. And that is that it's a bad idea. For the reasons stated in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

What is important to note is that `i = i + 1;` does not really change i. It only changes your local copy of `i` (in other words, the `i` in the calling code won't change).

Based on that, it is a matter of readability and avoiding unexpected behaviour in your code by complying with [the POLS (Principle Of Least Surprise)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: It changes the local `i` but not the original value passed as the parameter, which doesn't have to be called `i` and indeed doesn't even have to be a variable.

Answer (score 3):

> Since i is passed by value it is safe to change it `foo()`

It is absolutely safe even when you pass an object reference because they are local: i.e., assigning a new reference to the local reference will not have any impact on the original reference in the calling code

It's your personal choice. However i would not change the argument values as one might loose the track of the actual value passed in to this method.

Comment: True and important to know. But you should write this in a comment, not in an answer. Also note that OP never implied otherwise.

Comment: Ok. Btw what does OP mean? I am newbie :)

Comment: No worries. OP = Original Post(er), i.e. Michael who asked this question.

Answer (score 1):

Neutral. But it would be considered a better practice by many people to change the method to:

```
void foo(final int i) {
    int j = i + 1; // not change i
    ...
}
```

Feel free to work either way.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on context. I lean towards "bad practice", for two reasons:

1. Some people may think the original value is being changed.
2. It *may* make the code harder to reason about (mitigated with appropriately-short methods).

A third issue pops up when it's a reference value. If you modify the parameter reference to point at something else and change its state, the original *won't* be modified–this may or may not be what's intended. If you create another reference to the parameter and change the new reference's state, the parameter's reference *will* be changed–which *also* may or may not be what's intended.

Comment: #1 is not a good reason. If they don't know what argument passing style a method is using, they have worse problems than misunderstanding that one method and should learn that first before doing any more coding.

Comment: @delnan It's a fine reason--any obfuscation should be avoided when it can be, which it can be in this situation. You may not *agree* with the reason, which is fine.

Comment: Okay, I disagree with the reason. But not because I don't eschew obfuscation, but because I think the meaning it as obvious as the meaning of `a + 1` to everyone who actually knows the language.