# Why does assigning null to a node does not delete that node in a linked list

Tags: java, data-structures, singly-linked-list

To remove the last node of the list, I just traversed till the last node and assigned it to null.
But I still see the last node value. I am wondering why node = null does not have any effect.

```
void deleteLastNode(Node node){
    while(node.next != null)
    {
        node = node.next;
    }
    node = null;
}
```

Comment: Because Java arguments are passed by value. The variable `node` that you are reassigning only exists inside your method.

Comment: related: [Is it a good practice to change arguments in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019978/is-it-a-good-practice-to-change-arguments-in-java)

Comment: However `node.next = null;` *would* have an effect, for reasons explained in the duplicate.